# Can't open Minecraft Server for Internet

Tags: networking, router, firewall, port-forwarding, modem

I followed all the steps for hosting a Minecraft Server:

- Allowing connection (inbound and outbound, TCP and UDP) to port 25565 on Windows Firewall.
- Forwarding ports on router configuration (TCP and UDP, with 25565/25565 private/public ports) to my PC's static private IP (192.168.0.2).
- Opening server either with a blank "server-ip" or with 192.168.0.2 on that property.

But it still appearing as closed for my friends and port checking sites.

Is there any step I missed? Do I need to change some settings on my modem too?

Also, my modem (Motorola) has DHCP Server enabled. Does it have something to do with my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if your "modem" has a DHCP server, it's almost certainly more than a modem, it's a full-on NAT gateway router too. So you've been doing double NAT all this time without realizing it. Pick one device or the other to be your NAT gateway and DHCP server, and turn those features off in your other box, making it just a bridge.

If you're for some reason stuck with both acting as NAT gateways, you'll have to forward the 25535 ports from the "modem" to your other router, and then again from that router to your Minecraft server PC.